# Building table of unique sets

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, ddl

What I'm trying to do is build a table of unique sets of rows.

What is the aim?

I'm building an app for a service provider (let's say cable company for example). Every customer has a set of services on his connection. Every customer can have different number, type and combination of services installed.

For example some customers pays for standard cable package, they pay for HBO extra package and they also pays for online movie storage...

The system I'm building will allow the admin to create a migration. Each migration has groups and inside every group there is a matrix of service changes. Point is that the service provider is changing his portfolio and needs to migrate all the customers with certain combinations of services to different combinations.

Here's my SQL DDL code:

```
CREATE TABLE [Migration]
(  
    [MigrationId]   INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
    [Name]          VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [Description]   VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL
)

ALTER TABLE [Migration] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [Migration_pk] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([MigrationId]) 
                    WITH (ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON , ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON ) 

CREATE TABLE [Migration_Service_Group]
(
    [GroupId]       INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
    [MigrationId]   INT NOT NULL
)

ALTER TABLE [Migration_Service_Group] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [MigSerGroup_pk] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([GroupId]) 
                    WITH (ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON , ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON ) 

CREATE TABLE [Migration_Matrix]
(
    [MatrixId]      INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1), 
    [GroupId]       INT NOT NULL
    [ServiceType]   INT NOT NULL,
    [OldRefId]      INT NOT NULL,
    [NewRefId]      INT NOT NULL
)

ALTER TABLE [Migration_Matrix] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [MigMatrix_pk] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([MatrixId]) 
                    WITH (ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON , ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON ) 

ALTER TABLE [Migration_Service_Group]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [MigSerGroup_fk] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([MigrationId]) REFERENCES [Migration]([MigrationId])
                ON DELETE NO ACTION 
                ON UPDATE NO ACTION

ALTER TABLE [Migration_Matrix]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [MigMatrix_fk] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([GroupId]) REFERENCES [Migration_Service_Group]([GroupId])
                ON DELETE NO ACTION 
                ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

What I don't know how to do is enforcing this rule:

Every group is unique => every set of rows in table Migration_Matrix with GroupID is unique, so that there are no same or contradicting groups of rules for migration.

For example: Group 1 (Migration_matrix => Migration_service_group, GroupId:1) has these records:

```
1,1,1,145,156 
2,1,1,175,168
```

If Group 2 (Migration_matrix => Migration_service_group, GroupId:2) started like this, it would be error:

```
3,2,1,145, .... 
4,2,1,175, ....
```

Because it contradicts the first group. But if group2 had an extra rows (another service change) it should be OK.

Any idea how to enforce it on the database side?

Comment: This type of constraint is better served on app side. When a user  starts to create/modify a matrix for a group the app locks the group. When a user  hits Save the app checks constraints, updates the db and unlocks the group.

Comment: Yeah, thought so myself. Post this please as an answer. If no one has better idea in few days I'l mark it as solution.

Comment: What makes group 2 exactly "contradict" group 1?  Is it because two groups can't have the same `OldRefId` for the same `ServiceType` ?

Comment: @DavidWaldo . . . I'm lost.  You have described several tables, none of which are called `group`.  I don't know how to interpret your strings of numbers.  All the tables have multiple columns.  It is really confusing.

Comment: Sorry if it is confusing. Every row in Migration_Matrix belongs to a Group. Groups are in the Migration_Service_Group table. 1,1,1,145,156 tells you: MatrixId: 1, GroupId: 1, ServiceType: 1, OldRefId: 145, NewRefId: 156. So first group is set of rules how to migrate customers that have service 145 and 175 of serviceType 1. You cant have another group migrating the same combination of OldRefId with serviceType 1.

Comment: So then wouldn't it be solved if there's a unique constraint/index on (ServiceType, OldRefId) in Migration_Matrix?  Then you can't insert duplicate (ServiceType, OldRefId) tupples.

Comment: No...there can be duplicate rows. There cant be duplicate sets of rows (hence the name of the question). rows are grouped to sets by groupId. Basicly Group one tells you how to migrace every customer that has service id 145 of type 1 and service id of 175 type 1. You cant have another group that tells the same. Buf if group 2 had another condition, for example telling you how ti migrate customer witch services 145,175,161 all with type 1, then thats OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of constraint is better served on the app side. When a user starts to create/modify a matrix for a group the app locks the group. When a user hits Save the app checks constraints, updates the db and unlocks the group.